# QNetworkAccessManager https UnknownNetworkError when using pyside2

Tags: python, pyside2, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I’m using the QNetworkAccessManager module and it works fine with HTTP requests, but when I try to do https requests it fails and returns:

```
PySide2.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NetworkError.UnknownNetworkError
and error string: TLS initialization failed
```

this problem only happens with pyside2 on windows but it works fine on Mac os.

when I used the same piece of code with pyqt5 it worked just fine on both Windows and Mac os.

### https requests:

- pyside2 on windows: fails
- pyside2 on mac: works fine
- on windows: works fine
- pyqt5 on mac: works fine

and I’m stuck with it for a while and can’t seem to find the problem.

I’m using python 3.7 and pyside2 5.15.
also, I tested with pyside2 5.12.6 and the same error occurs.

```
from PySide2 import QtNetwork
from PySide2 import QtCore
import sys, json

class Example:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.handle_response)
    
    def do_request(self):
        url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.nam.get(req)
    
    def handle_response(self, reply):
        er = reply.error()
        if er == QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:
            bytes_string = reply.readAll()
            print(str(bytes_string, 'utf-8'))
        else:
            print(f'Error occurred: {er}: {reply.errorString()}')
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

def main():
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    ex.do_request()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: it seems to be an OpenSSL problem

Comment: then how to fix it.
and why pyqt5 is working just fine?

Comment: I'm having the same issue i don't know how to fix this